# Can't see "x:Name" from XAML in CS

Tags: c#, xamarin

My CS does not see a x:Name resource defined in my XAML. The 'Image x:Name="Imag1" ' must be missing something obvious.  Can someone help?

XAML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsCamera" x:Class="EnSpect.XamarinFormsCameraPage">     
    <StackLayout Padding="20">
        <Button Text="Select Image" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="SelectImageClicked"></Button>
        <Image x:Name="Imag1"  Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="300"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage>
```

CS:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EnSpect
 {
   public partial class XamarinFormsCameraPage : ContentPage
  {
    public XamarinFormsCameraPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<byte[]>(this, "ImageSelected", (args) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                //Set the source of the image view with the byte array
                Imag1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream((byte[])args));
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is you XAML actually compiling properly? i.e. do you have the `SelectImageClicked` handler implemented that is in your XAML?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  No - my code is not compiling.  I tried a "SelectImageClicked" event in XAML.  Intellisense did not recognize that command.  I put it in and had receiver routine in CS, but it did not work - would not compile and still "Imag1" does not exist

Comment: Comment out the `Imag1` usage and compile again to see if the XAML is being parsed corrected, if not that is your problem.

Comment: OK - let me try that

Comment: Commenting out (  //                Imag1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream((byte[])args));) worked - it compiled

Comment: It also runs - up to the point I need that commented line to be executed

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently and just decided to leave my solution here. I clicked the arrow next to ExampleView.xaml > ExampleView.xaml.cs > ExampleView and opened InitializeComponent. Inside of there you'll see all of the referenced elements in private void InitializeComponent if I wanted to add a label I do it like this

```
ExampleLabel = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Label>(this, "ExampleLabel");
```

And above the private void InitializeComponent you'll want to add

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
private global::Xamarin.Forms.Label ExampleLabel;
```

And you should notice another file being generated and then I was able to reference my element.

Hope that helps!

Edit: This is only if adding x:Name="PropertyName" doesn't work